# angular service expected 1-2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have api url like this:

```
https://example.com/api/tickets?filters=[{"field":"ticket_number","op":"like","value":"HT00002"}]
```

And I've created service function like this:

```
getTableFilter(column: string, sort: string, value: string) {
    const accessToken = store.get('accessToken')
    const params = accessToken
      ? {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Token ${accessToken}`,
          AccessToken: accessToken,
        },
      }
      : {}
    return this.http
      .get(`${this.env.HELPDESK_LIST_FILTER}` + '[{field:' + column, + 'op:' + sort, + 'value:' + value + '}]', params)
      .pipe(map((data) => data));
}
```

> Note: `this.env.HELPDESK_LIST_FILTER` is equal to `'https://example.com/api/tickets?filters='` in my `env` file

But I get this error

[image: one]

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma should be in the quote.

```
return this.http
  .get(`${this.env.HELPDESK_LIST_FILTER}` + '[{field:' + column + ',op:' + sort + ',value:' + value + '}]', params)
  .pipe(map((data) => data));
```

Answer (score 2):

you have accidently apply more that two parameter try to stick with `` string format

```js
 this.http.get(`url`,params)
```

```js
const url = `${this.env.HELPDESK_LIST_FILTER}[{field: ${column},op:${sort},value:${value}}]`;

const params = accessToken 
     ? {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Token ${accessToken}`,
          AccessToken: accessToken,
        },
      }
      : {};

return this.http
  .get(url, params)
  .pipe(map((data) => data));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend to create a String before the call and assign the value instead of creating the String in the Get Request,

```
  const serviceUrl = `${this.env.HELPDESK_LIST_FILTER}` + '[{field:' + column, + 'op:' + sort, + 'value:' + value + '}]';
  return this.http
      .get(serviceUrl,params)
      .pipe(map((data) => data));
```